# Not able to run my cucumber script through command Prompt

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I have written a script to run my web application.[Below is the structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3tMN.jpg)

1. Feature: It has the code which will run the program in Web application.
2. Objects: It contains all the objects.
3. Reusable: It contains all the reusable code.
4. Runner: It contains Runner file which will run the feature.
5. User Story: Which contains all the ".feature" file.

I want to run this code in Command Prompt.. Can anyone help me on this? I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLI runner, [see the documentation here](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner)

From the documentation:

```
Usage: java cucumber.api.cli.Main [options] [[[FILE|DIR][:LINE[:LINE]*] ]+ | @FILE ]

Options:

  -g, --glue PATH                        Where glue code (step definitions, hooks

Feature path examples:
  <path>                                 Load the files with the extension ".feature"
                                         for the directory <path   
                                         and its sub directories.
  <path>/<name>.feature                  Load the feature file <path>/<name>.feature
                                         from the file system.
  classpath:<path>/<name>.feature        Load the feature file <path>/<name>.feature
                                         from the classpath.
  <path>/<name>.feature:3:9              Load the scenarios on line 3 and line 9 in
                                         the file <path>/<name>.feature.
  @<path>/<file>                         Parse <path>/<file> for feature paths generated
                                         by the rerun formatter.
```

Comment: I was able to run the program through command prompt. 
command: mvn test.

However, it was not able to open the browser and run the application.

Comment: D:\Paresh\Selenium Projects\P10_BaaS_Designer>mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building P10_BaaS_Designer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ P10_BaaS_
esigner ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

Comment: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Paresh\Selenium Projects\P10_BaaS
Designer\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ P10_BaaS_Desig
er ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ P
0_BaaS_Designer ---

Comment: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Paresh\Selenium Projects\P10_BaaS
Designer\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ P10_Ba
S_Designer ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ P10_BaaS_Designer
---

Comment: [INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.790 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-16T01:13:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/114M
[INFO] ---------------